# Calculating accuracy within excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Prediction cell (A1), a Results cell (B1) and a Difference cell (C1) in MS Excel.  I have an Accuracy cell (D1) that I would like to show the accuracy of the prediction based on the result.

For example, if I have 24 as a prediction and 24 as the result, the accuracy should be 100% with a difference of 0.  If I have a prediction of 24 and a result of 12, then the accuracy should be 50% with a difference of -12. If I have a prediction of 24 and a result of 48, then the accuracy should be 50% with a difference of 12.

Here is the calculation I'm using in the Accuracy cell (D1):

`=(((C1+100)*A1)/B1)/(C1+100)`

This calculation is only showing the expected results when the Prediction cell is higher than or equal to the Results cell.

Comment: try: =IF(C1<0,"-","")&(B1/A1)*100&"%"

Comment: what value do you expect when you have a prediction of 24 and a result of 48, also 50%?

Comment: @K_B In that case, yes, the accuracy should also be 50% but the Difference cell value would be 12 rather than -12. Good point! I edited OP's question accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to have a difference of 12 if the prediction is 24 and the result is 48.

Answer (score 3):

Its a pretty simple forumla as far as i can see.

If A1 is the cell with the prediction in and A2 is the Actual result then use this formula

```
=IF(A1<A2,A1/A2,A2/A1)
```

This gives the percentage of prediction vs actual in either case

experimentally, when the following values were used, then the following results came from this cell

1. Prediction: 2 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 20%
2. Prediction: 4 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 40%
3. Prediction: 6 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 60%
4. Prediction: 8 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 80%
5. Prediction: 10 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 100%
6. Prediction: 12 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 83%
7. Prediction: 14 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 71%
8. Prediction: 16 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 63%
9. Prediction: 18 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 56%
10. Prediction: 20 | Actual 10 | Accuracy: 50%

Hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Format the cell in Col C as "%" and then try this formula

Formula in C1 as per the snapshot

```
=IF(B1<A1,VALUE("-"&(B1/A1)),(B1/A1))
```

Formula in D1 as per the snapshot

```
=B1-A1
```

Various test Scenarios below.

[image]

Let me know if I have misunderstood your question and I will rectify my answer.

**FOLLOWUP**

Try this new formula

```
=IF(B1<A1,VALUE("-"&(B1/A1)),IF(B1=A1,B1/A1,(B1-A1)/A1))
```

Comment: Ahhh, so the prediction 48 of a real value of 24 is 200% accurate !  That's got be way better than only 100% accurate.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout  this is almost perfect, but the only issue I have is a user who gets the predictions  24 out of 24 will get 100% while the person who predicted 24 of 48 will get 200%.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout if B>A this means the prediction was smaller than the result and the number should be in the positive.  if A>B than the prediction was more then the result and the user over predicted meaning the % should be in the negative.

Comment: @need2nobasis: so for 24,36 it should be +50%, Similarly for 24,30 it should be +25%?

Comment: @need2nobasis: I have updated the post above. See the new formula in FOLLOWUP.

Comment: @SiddharthRout sorry for the delayed response, please forgive.  the follow up formula  suggests 8,8 is 100% which is correct.  But 2,8 is 300% which is not.  Maybe I need to simplify what I am trying to do.  The closer I get to the result number with the prediction without going over will lead up to 100% (i.e. 4,8 = 50% and 8,8 = 100%.  but as the prediction number exceeds the results number, the outcome should be more and more into the negative 10,8 = -25% and 14,8 = -75%

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=(1 - ((B1 - A1)/A1)) * 100
```

**EDIT:**

I just gave it more thought. It looks like the definition of accurate is quite subjective here. Try the following formula and let me know if this works any better.

```
=(1-(ABS(B1-A1)/A1))*100
```

Comment: And the morale is: Simple calculations should have simple formulas. +1.

Comment: @dotNET thanks for the response, unfortunately this didn't work.  For example, the 24 prediction with the 24 result returned an accuracy of 0.

Comment: @need2nobasis: Edited my answer. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

=MIN(A1:B1)/MAX(A1:B1)

Answer (score 0):

Below formula will give the accuracy `%ge` in Excel.
Click on the `%` button after applying it:

```
=1-(ABS((Predicted/Actual)-1))
```